# Unable to install suggested plugins of jenkins on docker

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I had launched jenkins through docker, it has been launched in administrator mode. After entering password when i selected to install suggested plugin it fails with most of the installation. Post that when i created jenkins user and navigated to jenkins home page it displays errors as shown in below screenshot.

[image]

Installed docker and jenkins through below commands

```
sudo yum install docker-ce

systemctl start docker

docker pull Jenkins

docker run -p 8080:8080 jenkins
```

Also when i go to manage jenkins and trying to install some other plugins like Git, it fails. I am not sure what is wrong with it? Why installation is failing.

Below is the log being printed by jenkins while installation.

[image]

Also below is the screenshot of warning mesage i am getting while installing through plugin manager

[image]

Comment: did you install the common plugin in the init process

Comment: @LinSel it fails installing common plugins as well during init process. only some of the plugins has been installed.

Comment: that right , I had that too, I suggest to use previous image tag, so not the latest

Comment: @LinSel This is first time i am configuring jenkins through docker, and i do not have any previous image.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had the same issue when using the `latest weekly`, so I suggest to use the `lts` since when specify `jenkins` in your command you are pulling `latest weekly`

run your command like this:

```
docker pull jenkins/jenkins:lts
docker run -p 8080:8080 jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

see [jenkins](https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/jenkins)

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this error too. Noticed that Jenkins needs a volume to be mounted to store all the plugin data. According to the [documentation](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/README.md), running this way would create /var/jenkins_home on the host system and resolved the errors given by OP.

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -d -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home jenkins/jenkins:lts
```