# Unable to start jenkins dashboard through Docker

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

I have installed docker and pulled jenkins image. Now when i am running jenkins through docker,

```
 root@ip-172-**-*7-**:~# docker run --name MyJenkins -p 8082:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v jenkins-data jenkins
```

it is getting started(saying jenkins is fully up and running) but executing jenkins url(http://localhost:8082/) on browser it is saying unable to connect to jenkins
[image]

Here is the jenkins logs and error being diplayed on machine(ec2 linux instance).

[image]

I don't know what's going wrong, Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to install suggested plugins of jenkins on docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56849717/unable-to-install-suggested-plugins-of-jenkins-on-docker)

Comment: you already asked that before :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to Connect to Jenkins Server (Amazon Linux AMI)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41055669/unable-to-connect-to-jenkins-server-amazon-linux-ami)

Comment: @LinPy No its a different question, here i am unable to get loggedIn to the Jenkins dashboard, while earlier question was unable to install jenkins plugin after getting loggedIn.

Comment: the Idea is you can not rely on the latest weekly images , they are sometime buggy